# Need XLST to change value of a node based on another node

Tags: xslt

I need XSLT to change the value of `Enabled` to `False` if the `Name` is `XYZ` in the below XML file.

My XML file is:

```
<MyRoot>
    <Category>
       <Name>XYZ</Name>
       <Location>mylocation</Location>
       <Enabled>True</Enabled>
    </Category>
    <Category>
       <Name>ABC</Name>
       <Location>mylocation1</Location>
       <Enabled>True</Enabled>
    </Category>
    <Category>
       <Name>DEF</Name>
       <Location>mylocation2</Location>
       <Enabled>True</Enabled>
    </Category>
</MyRoot>
```

Comment: By "change the value of Enabled to False" do you mean change all `Enabled` elements in the sample xml to false, or change some other enabled value to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would handle it:

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Category[Name='ABC']/Enabled">
    <Enabled>False</Enabled>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<MyRoot>
   <Category>
      <Name>XYZ</Name>
      <Location>mylocation</Location>
      <Enabled>False</Enabled>
   </Category>
   <Category>
      <Name>ABC</Name>
      <Location>mylocation1</Location>
      <Enabled>True</Enabled>
   </Category>
   <Category>
      <Name>DEF</Name>
      <Location>mylocation2</Location>
      <Enabled>True</Enabled>
   </Category>
</MyRoot>
```

Comment: More typical: `Category[Name='ABC']/Enabled` or `Enabled[../Name='ABC']` if you like.